# uninstall libc6 package by dpkg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have install "libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb" on my ubuntu server 12.04. The orginal libc6 on system is 2.15. After install the package, I check it by:

```
ldd --version
```

it shows:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) 2.15
```

not change. Then I found I can not install anything which depends on libc6 by apt-get, it will reports:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
```

So I try to uninstall the debian package, first I check:

```
dpkg -l | grep libc6
ii  libc6            2.17-0ubuntu5.1       Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev        2.15-0ubuntu10.5      Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
```

Then

```
dpkg -r libc6
```

It prints a alot of packages which depends on libc6 and tell me:

```
dpkg: error processing libc6 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6
```

It seems it doesn't know there are 2 version libc6 on system.

Use

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

gets:

```
libc6                                           deinstall
libc6-dev                                       install
```

How should I do?

Comment: Download a copy of the original 2.15 libc6 from the Ubuntu website, and reinstall it.  The stop, do not try to manually force an upgrade of this.  You will/have badly trash your system.

Comment: What's the reason of trash my system? Install package not supposed to be install on my system? How would I know that? It gives no warning when install. I install that because I build a program on ubuntu desktop and run it on ubuntu server, the glibc version is not match, so I find glibc on desktop and install it on server

Answer (score 6):

I have reinstall it by aptitude. It much powerful than apt-get and dpkg, none of them reinstall works.

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libc6

The following packages will be REINSTALLED:
  libc6 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is installed.
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is installed.
 libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 is installed.
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the libc6 package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:                                                                     
1)     libc-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.5 (now, precise-security, precise-updates) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10 (precise)]    
2)     libc-dev-bin [2.15-0ubuntu10.5 (now, precise-security, precise-updates) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10 (precise)]
3)     libc6 [2.17-0ubuntu5.1 (now) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10 (precise)]                                           
4)     libc6-dev [2.15-0ubuntu10.5 (now, precise-security, precise-updates) -> 2.15-0ubuntu10 (precise)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,852 kB of archives. After unpacking 88.1 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
```

As aptitude says, there are 4 packages belong to libc6, but I only install one of them by deb file. Maybe that is the reason trash the system

Answer (score 5):

As @jean mentioned you need to downgrade the package to your system's needs:

1. Check which version on ubuntu you're using
2. Download the libc6 or related deb packages from this [link](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/).
3. You are gonna install the .deb file you downloaded via terminal using this command: e.g.

```
sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure '/home/your-system-name/Downloads/libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Similarly, you can type `sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure` & drag and drop the
.deb file then you will get similar as above.**

4. Then after it has installed, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install
```

5. You can also use the **Synaptic Package Manager** to reinstall any missing packages.

You'll be okay. I had to downgrade my libc6-2.30 to libc6-2.28-10 on Zorin OS 15.2 today and it worked.